# pivot_table with group and without value field

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame url like

```
location  dom_category
3         'edu'
3         'gov'
3         'edu'
4         'org'
4         'others'
4         'org'
```

and i want this data frame to be like

```
location  edu   gov   org   others
3         2     1     0     0
4         0     0     2     1
```

the edu,gov,org and others contains the count for specific location.
i have right the code but i know its not the optimized

```
url['val']=1
url_final=url.pivot_table(index=['location'],values='val',columns=
['dom_category'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First if necessary remove `'` by [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html).

Then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['dom_category'] = df['dom_category'].str.strip("\'")
df = df.groupby(['location','dom_category']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
dom_category  edu  gov  org  others
location                           
3               2    1    0       0
4               0    0    2       1
```

Or use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['dom_category'] = df['dom_category'].str.strip("\'")
df=df.pivot_table(index='location',columns='dom_category',aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
print (df)
dom_category  edu  gov  org  others
location                           
3               2    1    0       0
4               0    0    2       1
```

Last is possible convert index to column and remove columns name `dom_category` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   location  edu  gov  org  others
0         3    2    1    0       0
1         4    0    0    2       1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupby` and `value_counts`

**House Keeping**
*get rid of **`'`***

```
df.dom_category = df.dom_category.str.strip("'")
```

**Rest of Solution**

```
df.groupby('location').dom_category.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

dom_category  edu  gov  org  others
location                           
3               2    1    0       0
4               0    0    2       1
```

To get the formatting just right

```
df.groupby('location').dom_category.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0) \ 
  .reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)

   location  edu  gov  org  others
0         3    2    1    0       0
1         4    0    0    2       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `str.strip`, `get_dummies` and `groupby`:

```
df['dom_category'] = df.dom_category.str.strip("\'")
df.assign(**df.dom_category.str.get_dummies()).groupby('location').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   location  edu  gov  org  others
0         3    2    1    0       0
1         4    0    0    2       1
```

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df.dom_category).groupby(df.location).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks.